# 'conda env list' from inside Python shell

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I know I can look up the list of conda environments by typing 'conda env list' on the unix terminal. However, I wish to pull that off from within the Python shell (as I need to know if certain conda environments were already created or not). To give some additional background, I am using Python 3+ .

So far, i have tried:

`subprocess.check_output('conda env list')`

However, I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conda env list'`

I tried other methods to write the 'conda evn list' onto the terminal but kept getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success with:

```
ret = subprocess.check_output('conda env list', shell=True)
print ret
```

*Caveat: Only tested with 2.7*

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks! I guess certain commands only work if I write it to the bash shell directly.